# MeteorJS Cant use node libraries on server side with typescript?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use angular 2 meteor and I'm having some issues using node libraries such as FS on the server side.

`import fs from 'fs';`

results in:

```
(3, 16): Cannot find module 'fs'.
20170625-07:41:23.740(3)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined
W20170625-07:41:23.740(3)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.wordGraph.wordGraph.js (server/wordGraph/wordGraph.ts:8:3)
W20170625-07:41:23.740(3)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20170625-07:41:23.741(3)? (STDERR)     at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20170625-07:41:23.741(3)? (STDERR)     at server/main.ts:5:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Npm.require` instead like

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```